# Property 'index' does not exist on type 'History<unknown>' using MemoryRouter in react-router-dom@5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to access the property `index` from history object when using `MemoryRouter`, but it generates a Typescript error, since the `index` attribute is not in the type definitions of `history` object. Here is the error:

```
Property 'index' does not exist on type 'History<unknown>'.
```

But the `index` attribute is there when I console.log the history object. Here is an example of history's state:

```
action: "POP"
block: ƒ block(prompt)
canGo: ƒ canGo(n)
createHref: ƒ createPath(location)
entries: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
go: ƒ go(n)
goBack: ƒ goBack()
goForward: ƒ goForward()
index: 0
length: 5
listen: ƒ listen(listener)
location: {pathname: '/app', search: '', hash: '', state: undefined, key: 't5skrl'}
push: ƒ push(path, state)
replace: ƒ replace(path, state)
```

I know that it is possible to provide a type for `useHistory` hook, but i've tried doing like `useHistory<{ index: number }>()` and it didn't solve the problem.

Code example:

```
import { MemoryRouter, Route, Switch, useHistory } from "react-router-dom"

const App = () => {
  return (
    <MemoryRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Page} />
      </Switch>
    </MemoryRouter>
  )
}

const Page = () => {
  const history = useHistory()
  console.log(history.index)

  return (
    <div>Page</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: `history` to the best of my knowledge doesn't have an `index` property. What is your code doing that is throwing this error/warning? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @DrewReese for regular history or BrowserRouter history that's correct, but react-router adds special attributes to history when we are using MemoryRouter

Comment: I see, yes, [MemoryHistory](https://github.com/remix-run/history/blob/main/packages/history/index.ts#L309-L318) adds an `index` property. So the issue here it seems is how to get your `useHistory` hook to "know" it's returning a `MemoryHistory` object, yes?

Comment: @DrewReese correct, make it clear for typescript that `MemoryHistory` special attributes are going to be returned.

Comment: After standing up a codesandbox using Typescript, `react-router-dom@5` and the `useHistory` hook I am unable to reproduce the error you describe. Can you edit your question to include a relevant code example that is producing this error?

Comment: Very similar to the code I used earlier. I've swapped in your code and still don't see any Typescript error specific to the `history` object. Can you reproduce issue in a *running* codesandbox we can inspect? Here's my [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/property-index-does-not-exist-on-type-historyunknown-using-memoryrouter-k43f4i) code if you want to fork it and update it to more closely match your actual code, including dependencies.

Comment: @DrewReese you should have installed `@types/react-router-dom`. Here's my [fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/property-index-does-not-exist-on-type-historyunknown-using-memoryrouter-forked-0ry7qs?file=/src/App.tsx).

Comment: I had done that in my previous sandbox and it didn't seem to affect any change for the imports, but I see it working as expected in your fork. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Import `MemoryHistory` from the `history` package and declare the returned `history` value from `useHistory` as a `MemoryHistory` object.

Example:

```
import { Switch, Route, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { MemoryHistory } from "history";

const Page = () => {
  const history = useHistory() as MemoryHistory;
  console.log(history.index);

  return <div>Page</div>;
};
```

[image: Edit property-index-does-not-exist-on-type-historyunknown-using-memoryrouter (forked)]